# Creating surrounding areas from a desert

Tags: environment, geography

**Based on this [question and answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/55052/constructing-a-desert-area).**

I was wondering how would the limits between Gretland and Winthold would be.

- Which temperatures would be have?
- What type of terrain would the limits of the desert be like?
- How would they mark the limits between the kingdoms?
- How would the limit with the mountains be like?

In the surroundings areas near the mountains of Gretland and Winthold I wanted to have forest; Winthold having a [boreal forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boreal_forest_of_Canada), while Gretland having a forest like the [ones on Englad](http://pixdaus.com/files/items/pics/8/69/268869_e9ea3f2393329a439d4f3a8f84812f68_large.jpg) and on [Andin-Patagonia Argentina](http://www.welcomeargentina.com/sanmartindelosandes/imagenes/otono-san-martin-andes-63.jpg).

- Are these forest possible due to the desert being near?

If answer is no,

- What would I have to change in order to make this forest possible?

[image: mapmap]
Note: Desert may be a bit smaller, this is just a aproximation to what I'm intending to create.

Comment: There is an abundance of questions here, and they aren't all directly related to each other. I would suggest removing a few questions to focus on the one geographical/climatological problem you want help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what your world would look like more or less...
[image]

With borders...
[image]

You can probably add forests to Winthold, but they'd be more sparse. The border of gretland in the south that i have with another country to the west should be moved more between the forest than following the river... my mistake but i dont want fix right now.

The terrain of the desert... Not so much that it would terrain in the desert but if you look at the west side of the desert and south you see that it is more green. That would be more of a steppes/plains than a desert. Likewise those rives would likely have swamps and farmland all up and down them, even in the desert... They'd be pretty visible in fact.

Also, the capital of Thaliak would be at the point where those 2 rivers come together... Gretland's would probably be closer to the mountain and mining, while the country to the west would be a harbor city at the gulf meeting the river. Winthold I have no clue where it would be as capitals in those types of regions are more random... maybe central in its territory, maybe near the ocea to the north, maybe close to the mountains.

Anyways, if you really want good advice on this stuff more than what this site is likely going to give you, especially since everything you have to think to ask first, You should check out http://cartographersguild.com I literally made this map in like a half hour to hour, with most of the time spent on loading programs, waiting for an algorythm to run, and drawing up those borders, and remembering how to do that scatter effect for the forrest. (btw this is the first time i got that to look good enough imo for the map and these maps are low quality even for me imo so yay ^.^ I still don't think they're probably good enough to use on a real map I'd make.)

Answer (score 2):

**Which temperatures would be have?**

A desert at this latitute would resemble interior deserts in Asia and North America. Here are some cities that your climate might be like: [Boise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boise,_Idaho#Climate), [Yining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yining_City#Climate), [St. George, UT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._George,_Utah#Climate), [Yinchuan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yinchuan#Climate).

**What type of terrain would the limits of the desert be like?**

Deserts grading into northern forest would look like the [Forest-Steppe transition](http://www.greenpeace.org/russia/en/campaigns/world-natural-heritage/daurian-steppes/) of Russia. In the more mountainous areas it would look like the [North Central Rockies Forest](https://www.google.com/search?q=North%20Central%20Rockies%20forests&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjyqteS_5PPAhUKOyYKHWPiAgYQ_AUICigD&biw=1280&bih=845).

Non-tropical desert-forest transitions with a desert poleward are rare, some examples would be the southern [Manchurian plains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolian-Manchurian_grassland), the mountain forests of [Turkey/Caucausus/Iran](http://wwf.panda.org/about_our_earth/ecoregions/caucasus_temperate_forests.cfm), and the Huang He basin of China, which is unfortunately all farmland now on account of the hundreds of millions of Chinese that spent the last few millenia there.

**Types of Forest**

Gretland couldn't look like the forests of England. In order to have a desert to its north and still be a forest, Gretland is going to need hot wet summers, possibly monsoon driven. It would be more like Southern China, or the Gulf Coast of the US.

Patagonia doesn't have forests at all. It looks like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=patagonia%20south%20america&biw=1280&bih=845&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtrMbmgZTPAhUHUSYKHfKoAksQ_AUIBygC#tbm=isch&q=patagonian%20plains).

**Are these forest possible due to the desert being near?**

Yes I gave several examples above. There needs to a transition area of scrub-steppe, to grassland, to forest-steppe, perhaps 500km across at minimum.

Comment: I made a mistake writting only patagonia, it was [andin patagonia](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=patagonia+andina&client=ubuntu&hs=VfG&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmpp-qhZTPAhWCDJAKHUvkCdAQ_AUICCgB&biw=1280&bih=895)

Comment: Either way, Patagonian plains or mountains, its a very southerly locale. Your Gretland has to be more equatorial so you should be looking at hotter comparisons.